# R - emulate the default behavior of hist() with ggplot2 for bin width

Tags: r, histogram, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot an histogram for one variable with ggplot2. Unfortunately, the default binwidth of ggplot2 leaves something to be desired:

[image: default ggplot2 output]

I've tried to play with `binwidth`, but I am unable to get rid of that ugly "empty" bin:

[image: ggplot2 output with tweaked binwidth]

Amusingly (to me), the default `hist()` function of R seems to produce a much better "segmentation" of the bins:

[image: default output of hist]

Since I'm doing all my other graphs with ggplot2, I'd like to use it for this one as well - for consistency. How can I produce the same bin "segmentation" of the `hist()` function with ggplot2?

I tried to input `hist` at the terminal, but I only got

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("hist")
<bytecode: 0x2f44940>
<environment: namespace:graphics>
```

which bears no information for my problem.

I am producing my histograms in ggplot2 with the following code:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=myvariable)) + geom_histogram(color="darkgray",fill="white", binwidth=61378) + scale_x_continuous("My variable") + scale_y_continuous("Subjects",breaks=c(0,2.5,5,7.5,10,12.5),limits=c(0,12.5)) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))
```

One thing I should add is that looking at the histogram produced by`hist()`, it would seem that the bins have a width of 50000 (e.g. from 1400000 to 1600000 there are exactly two bins); setting binwidth to 50000 in ggplot2 *does not* produce the same graph. The graph produced by ggplot2 has the same gap.

Comment: I really wish that geom_histogram would have the same default behavior as the native hist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without sample data, it's always difficult to get reproducible results, so i've created a sample dataset

```
set.seed(16)
mydata <- data.frame(myvariable=rnorm(500, 1500000, 10000))

#base histogram
hist(mydata$myvariable)
```

As you've learned, `hist()` is a generic function. If you want to see the different implementations you can type `methods(hist)`. Most of the time you'll be running `hist.default`. So if be borrow the break finding logic from that funciton, we come up with

```
brx <- pretty(range(mydata$myvariable), 
    n = nclass.Sturges(mydata$myvariable),min.n = 1)
```

which is how `hist()` by default calculates the breaks. We can then use these breaks with the `ggplot` command

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=myvariable)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="darkgray",fill="white", breaks=brx) + 
    scale_x_continuous("My variable") + 
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold"))
```

and the plot below shows the two results side-by-side and as you can see they are quite similar.

[image]

Also, that empty bim was probably caused by your y-axis limits. If a shape goes outside the limits of the range you specify in `scale_y_continuous`, it will simply get dropped from the plot. It looks like that bin wanted to be 14 tall, but you clipped y at 12.5.

Comment: How can one abstract this into a `geom_base_histogram()`? I.e. how to extract the `x` variable inside such a function?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to the one pointed out by @MrFlick.

You can define a function that will generate the width of the bins. For instance, if we use the number of classes used by the Sturges method (default of `hist`) the function looks as follows:

```
bins_sturges <- function(x) diff(range(x)) / nclass.Sturges(x)
```

Using the same data as in the previous examples, we have:

```
set.seed(16)
mydata <- data.frame(myvariable = rnorm(500, 1500000, 10000))

ggplot(my_data) +
   geom_histogram(aes(x = myvariable), 
                  color = "darkgray",
                  fill = "white", 
                  binwidth = bins_sturges)
```

And the result is
[image]

I like this solution better because we do not have to redefine the breaks separately for every variable we want to create a histogram.
Also, it works well with `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` (unlike the previous solution).