# Extracting numbers behind histogram R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution

I have this kind of data:

```
                  id count  total SEXO EDAD IDENTIF_AFILIADO idstring
 1:  952815090_12_06_Q643     4 133.34    M   39        952815090     Q643
 2:   952443257_10_17_C64     9  64.32    F    5        952443257      C64
 3:   931131767_9_10_C716     2  21.88    M    1        931131767     C716
 4:   931131767_8_13_C716    15 173.70    M    1        931131767     C716
 5:   931131767_1_09_C716     1  10.94    M    0        931131767     C716
```

...

Then I tried an histogram of the variable **total**, using the next code:

```
ggplot(frec_sev$sev,aes(x=total))+
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),color="black",fill="#17743c",alpha=0.8,bins=100)+
xlim(c(0,10000))+ylim(c(0,0.001))
```

the resulting plot is the next one:

[image]

I would like to know the rows associated to the largest bar around ~1200,  in order to extract that rows and then fit to a probability distribution such weibull for instance.

Comment: Binning data discards information - you'll have better results if you fit the distribution to the raw data rather than the binned data.

Comment: How to do it? I performed a distribution fitting like this:                                             
                                                                                                                               
 fit2<-fitdist(frec_sev$sev$total,distr="weibull",start=list(shape=0.1,scale=0.1),discrete = TRUE)

Comment: When I plotted the histogram and the fitted probability density, the largest bar does not seems correct.

Answer (score 4):

Extract the rows of raw data behind a histogram "peak" does not need to be done with graphic interaction. I'll demonstrate using `mtcars$disp`.

```r
H <- hist(mtcars$disp, plot = FALSE)
```

This plots nothing, but if it had then it would look like this:

[image: sample histogram]

If we look at the value of `H` returned by `hist`, we'll see several components:

```r
str(H)
# List of 6
#  $ breaks  : int [1:10] 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500
#  $ counts  : int [1:9] 5 7 4 1 4 4 4 1 2
#  $ density : num [1:9] 0.003125 0.004375 0.0025 0.000625 0.0025 ...
#  $ mids    : num [1:9] 75 125 175 225 275 325 375 425 475
#  $ xname   : chr "mtcars$disp"
#  $ equidist: logi TRUE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Namely, if we want the highest bar, we should find the max of `H$counts` (or `H$density`). Since we don't care about the actual value of that bar, just the bins, then

```r
which.max(H$counts)
# [1] 2
```

If you look at the output from `str(H)` above, recall that we see length 9 (the number of bars) for everything except `$breaks`, which defines the boundaries used for each bin. Since we want the breaks associated with `2`, we need the second and third:

```r
H$breaks[ 0:1 + which.max(H$counts) ]
# [1] 100 150
```

(which sounds right, interpreting the x-axis values in the plot above).

From there, we can easily filter the raw data to see which rows are contained within that bin.

```r
subset(mtcars, 100 <= disp & disp <= 150)
#                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710    22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D     24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230      22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Ferrari Dino  19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# Volvo 142E    21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

(Recall that the `H$counts` for bar 2 said "7", and we have 7 rows here.)

---

### `ggplot2` integration

In order to apply this to a plot rendered with `ggplot2`, we can immediately see that the plot looks different:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image: ggplot2 histogram of the same mtcars disp data]

In order to get a match, we need to control the number of bins used. Typically this is take as a "suggestion" and not a hard-and-fast number; for instance, `hist(mtcars$disp, breaks=10)` still produces 9 bins, and `breaks=20` produces 21 bins.

Up front, getting `hist` and `geom_histogram` to produce the same plot is fraught with peril: while the default number of bins is an easy thing to address, they deal with right/left boundaries differently. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150131/3358272

> `hist`: right-closed (left open) intervals. Default: `right = TRUE`
>
> `stat_bin` (`ggplot2`): left-closed (right open) intervals. Default: `right = FALSE`

(That answer is a little dated, `ggplot2` now uses `closed="right"` instead of `right=TRUE`.)

The only sure-fire way I've been able to make `hist` and `geom_histogram` *match* is by using my own breaks, something like

```r
brks <- seq(min(mtcars$disp), max(mtcars$disp), length.out = 10)
hist(mtcars$disp, breaks = brks)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp)) + geom_histogram(breaks = brks)
```

Comment: THanks for the answer, how to do a graphical representation of the data and the fitting??

Comment: Your question was *"know the rows associated to the largest bar"*. Once you subset the data, then you can try to fit the distribution of it. SO is not well-fit for tutorials or howtos, and I'm not able to write one atm. Good luck.