# Replicate hist breaks in ggplot without a function outside of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Histogram breaks

In base plot, when you use the `hist` function, it automatically calculates the breaks using the `nclass.Sturges` function, in ggplot however, you have to provide the breaks.

If I plot a histogram of the classical **faithfull** data I get the following graph:

```
data("faithful")
hist(faithful$waiting)
```

[image]

#### This works

I found out in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146544/r-emulate-the-default-behavior-of-hist-with-ggplot2-for-bin-width), that you can mimic the

```
library(tidyverse)
data("faithful")
brx <- pretty(range(faithful$waiting), n = nclass.Sturges(faithful$waiting), min.n = 1)
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="darkgray", fill="white", breaks=brx)
```

[image]

#### But this does not

But I would like to add the breaks within my ggplot function, so I tried this:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="darkgray", fill="white", 
                 aes(breaks=pretty(range(waiting), 
                                   n = nclass.Sturges(waiting), 
                                   min.n = 1)))
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: breaks
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (272): breaks, x
```

I understand what it means, but I can put Aesthetics of length one in aes, such as:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(waiting)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="darkgray", fill="white", breaks=brx, 
                 aes(alpha = 0.5))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on your data, `brx` is a vector of length 13, not length 1. In any case `geom_histogram` (which uses the same aesthetics as `geom_bar`) does not understand `breaks` as an aesthetic mapping, so even something like `aes(breaks = 1)` would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_histogram` uses the same `aes` as `geom_bar` according to the documentation and `breaks` isn't one of those aesthetics. (See [geom_bar](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html))

In the working code chunk you pass breaks to the function `geom_histogram` directly and that works, but in the problematic chunk you pass it as an aesthetic, and ggplot complains.

This works for me and I think does what you want:

```
ggplot(faithful, aes(x = waiting)) + 
geom_histogram(color = "darkgray", fill = "white", 
             breaks = pretty(range(faithful$waiting), 
                               n = nclass.Sturges(faithful$waiting), 
                               min.n = 1))
```